# Codeigniter not accepting jQuery POST with CSRF protection enabled

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I've been trying to POST to a Codeigniter controller (while CSRF protection is enabled) but this keeps failing with `HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error` and `This action is not allowed` page.

I tried sending the csrf token along with POST data using the following method (which I found [here](http://jerel.co/blog/2012/03/a-simple-solution-to-codeigniter-csrf-protection-and-ajax)) but it does not seem to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery.cookie.js"></script> 
<div id="display">Loading...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   // this bit needs to be loaded on every page where an ajax POST may happen
   $.ajaxSetup({
       data: {
           csrf_token: $.cookie('csrf_cookie')
        }
    });

   // now you can use plain old POST requests like always
   $.post('http://localhost/index.php/handler/test', { name : 'Grim'}, function(data){ $('#display').html(JSON.stringify(data)); });
```

Here's my Codeigniter `config.php` file:

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_token';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 1800;
```

Here's the controller:

```
function test()
{

    echo json_encode($_POST);
}
```

Comment: The script was to be used in Cordova, the mistake was that I set the target URL as `localhost` and once that was changed to the local IP things work in Cordova with Android emulator. But not with the browser. And hence this question is no longer relevant to me.

Answer (score 0):

add csrf token to data before posting

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: {'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>':'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>',/*----your data-----*/}

        })
```

csrf token needs to be send along every request so it needs to be specified by the above echo statements